Frequency estimation using Kalman filter
The question migth be very simple. I get a strange result from Kalman Filter. When I estimate the frequency and phase of complex signal $e^{j2\pi f + \theta }$ using the following
$F= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ $H= \begin{bmatrix}
cos(j2\pi f + \theta)\\
sen(j2\pi f + \theta)
\end{bmatrix}$
Non-linear measures are used to obtain innovations. Implementations are based on [1]
The output are the states
$x= \begin{bmatrix}
\theta\\
2\pi f 
\end{bmatrix}$
And for one set of $T_{sample}=1 s$ and modeling the complex envolving with $f < 0.5$ (Nyquist theorem). The filter always estimates half the frequency. It's like there's a number two missing somewhere.
[1] Grewal, M.S. and Andrews, A.P. (2014) Kalman Filtering Theory and Practice Using MATLAB. 4th Edition, John Wiley & Sons Inc., New York.

Honestly, there seems to be a lot of misconceptions here. I'll try to work out what I can, but there's a lot to dig through, so I can't promise my answer will get you a ton closer to what you are looking for.
First, $e^{j2\pi f + \theta}$ is not a complex signal, it's a complex number. You need $e^{j2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta}$, i.e., there has to be some sample or time indexing. Second, your Euler identity is wrong.
\begin{equation}
e^{j2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta} = \cos(2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta) + j\sin(2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta)
\end{equation}
However, if you are observing quadrature demodulated data, you are observing $\cos(2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta)$ and $\sin(2\pi fkT_{s}+\theta)$. So, you need to keep track of the states of the quadrature demodulated data, the frequency, and the phase. So your state vector would be
\begin{equation}
\underline{x}_{k} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta) \\ \sin(2\pi fkT_{s} + \theta) \\ \theta \\ 2\pi f \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{k}(1) \\ x_{k}(2) \\ x_{k}(3) \\ x_{k}(4) \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Since you observe the quadrature demodulated data, your measurement matrix is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The measurement matrix selects and scales which states are being observed, but doesn't introduce new observations. For the state transition matrix $\mathbf{F}$, we need to use trig identities to predict the next state. What we end up finding is that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F} = \begin{bmatrix}-\sin(x_{k}(4)T_{s}) & \cos(x_{k}(4)T_{s}) & 0 & 0 \\ \cos(x_{k}(4)T_{s}) & \sin(x_{k}(4)T_{s}) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & T_{s} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Notice that there is no update on the frequency. This requires that you have a reasonably accurate knowledge of $f$ beforehand, and that it doesn't change or is slowly varying. Additionally, the estimate of your phase is highly dependent on the initial phase guess. If the initial phase guess is incorrect, there will likely be some constant error in the phase. You could theoretically initialize the state based on the first measurement, though it wouldn't be denoised.
I can't promise that any of this is perfect as I haven't done frequency/phase estimation with Kalman filters before, but this should hopefully at least get you on the right track.

Hello. First thanks for your answer. Sorry for the mistake in the eq. of complex signal, I should have written the time sample. I understand your propose but I saw two problems that we can discuss. The measurement matrix should be the same that I wrote because this measures are non-linears and are the real and complex part of the complex signal. However, I can modelate the system to obtain this kinds of measures. The other point is that when you modelate the states, the third and fourth are the phase and frequency, where the third state is uncorrelate with itself, why?

@ArianSaggese Are you actually observing the imaginary part, or are you observing the part that's 90 degrees out of phase and then manipulating the math internally? And, in a constant frequency system, the change in phase from the previous sample is dependent on the time step and the frequency (phase is the integral of frequency). If there is not a constant frequency, you would have to find a way to measure the rate of change in frequency.

I am observing the imaginary and real parts of the complex signal. It is clear that the system has a constant frequency, but in the discrete state model with a simple first-order approximation, the F matrix results in [1 'T_s' ; 0 1] (\theta [n+1] = \theta [n] +T_s \Omega, and (\Omega [n+1] = \Omega[n])

@ArianSaggese Sorry, didn’t realize I was missing the 1 in my $\mathbf{F}$ matrix. Updated that. Then, if you are observing an imaginary number, you would change the 1 in the second row of $\mathbf{H}$ to $j$.
